# EEVEE Glass Shader

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, glass

I am in rendered view in the viewport and my glass shader isn't working correctly. I remember a couple months ago I was making glass for a ship and these settings are the only thing I had to mess around with:

[image]

So I added an hdri as the environment background and this is what happens:

[image]

Now the glass works for the environment but not for other objects, Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get transparency working with other objects in eevee, you have to tick a couple not-so-obvious boxes.

First, in Render Settings, tick **Screen Space Reflections**:
[image: Screenshot of side menu]

And then under screen space reflections, tick **Refraction**.

Then in the material menu of the *transparent* object, tick **Screen Space Reflections**:

[image: Material Menu of glass object]

Then adjust the refraction depths slider just below it. The default is 0m, which gives some really extreme refractions that doesn't look right. (EDIT: or maybe it does? Spheres are suppose to have inverted reflections)

The lower refraction depths is (excluding 0), the less refraction you get, so 0.0001m basically mean no refraction.

With a refraction depths of 1m, I get this:
[image: Render example]

There are still a few caveats though, mainly that (AFAIK) you can't have 2  objects that both have materials with SSR checked behind one another. The one behind will just not show up. You can however have a transparent object without SSR checked behind one with SSR. So this only matters if you have 3 or more objects in a row.

With refraction depths set to 0.0001,

Middle sphere without SSR:

[image]

Middle sphere with SSR:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Eevee is no raytracing renderer -- that is one reason, why it is so fast. To reveal the full beauty of transperancy you need Cycles, which does raytracing. Sorry for the bad news... ;) :)

Comment: I have had it working before when I made a ship in eevee just a couple months ago. I understand it's not a raytracing rendering engine but I know there is a way to get glass to work at least half decent. This glass just isn't working at all lol.