# How can I render the effect of "transparent" lenses in glasses to use in other software?

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders

[image]

I want to render that effect, but when I do it they simply transform into a solid texture. I'm using Eevee

Nodes:
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Can you [edit] your question to provide some additional info?  Which rendering engine are you using?  What does the lens material node tree look like?

Comment: @AllenSimpson Done my friend.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm really no good with eevee, just getting into it recently, but I'm sure someone will have an answer for you.  I do remember there being some settings for glass in Render Properties.

Comment: @AllenSimpson Which render do you use? Cycles? I can do it in Cycles. I'm still new to Blender, just trying to get stuff out :~)

Comment: Does this answer help? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/162826/110840

Comment: have you enabled Blend Mode > Alpha Blend in the Material > Settings?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to "bake" the transparency and refraction als some kind of texture, to export it into another software that doesn't support realtime refraction?

Comment: @haarigertroll woah woah take it easy, I'm new to this.

Comment: @dawn: Sorry, I was just trying to better understand what you are trying to do.
Let's try again: As far as I understand, you are happy the way it looks in blender, but want to export this look into some other software?

Comment: @haarigertroll Exactly. In my noobness I want that to happend, but in reality I don't know if it's possible or is it hard.

Comment: Then, I am afraid, this won't work. Rendering a transparent effect to a static texture will only ever work from one given angle. To my knowledge, there is no way of pre-rendering refraction for 3D-engines that don't support refraction. Could you tell us, which applications you want to export your model to?

Comment: @haarigertroll Max 8, with Jitter