# How to have actual see-through glass shaders in material preview?

Tags: materials, transparency, glass

I want to be able to see through my glass material in material preview mode, but all it will do is show a reflection of my HDRI. How do I make it actually see-through?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150804/eevee-glass-shader

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you are able to do that.

In order to see through an object you have to use rendered view.

Material view simply shows what material each object has, but it doesn't take a lot of other things into consideration.

Rendered view will take everything into consideration and show true transparency.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK The glass shader itself in EEVEE isn't transparent. If you mix the glass shader with transparent shader, you can see through like this in material preview:

[image]

> Note: you have to change the blend mode to see that effect: [image]