# Blender glass material for hollow box

Tags: materials, glass

I made a open box in blender with 2 boxes and boolean subtract.

When I change the material to glass with the shader

*Scene -> Screen Space Reflection*, Refraction set
*Material -> Settings -> Blend mode: Alpha Hashed*

[image]

[image]

but the inside of the box is not transparent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EEVEE Glass Shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150804/eevee-glass-shader)

Answer (score 2):

When you use booleans the material of second object join to the first

[image]

to fix that, you can change the solver of the boolean modifier to "Fast"

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it had something to do with the boolean operation. :)